is there any way to prove that the distance between two points with rational coordinates cannot be a multiple of sqrt(3) or otherwise
I want to prove that there exists no integer at a distance of any multiple of sqrt(3) from a straight line with integral roots

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

What are the roots of a line ? It is not an appropriate word particularly with a plural : 'roots' and not 'root' : indeed, a line never intersects the $x$ axis into 2 points exactly ! Do you mean the abscissa (resp. ordinate) of intersection with the $x$ (resp. $y$) axis ?
